# Edit Persistent object

Tags: blackberry

I need to edit the data stored in a persistent object.

I have some idea about this in Android -- there we use Editor to edit data in shared preference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the object stored in the PersistentObject, cast that object into whatever type it should be, make your changes and then commit the results back to the PersistentObject so your code would look something like this:

```
PersistentObject perstObj = PersistentStore.getPersistentObject(<UNIQUE KEY>);
MyClass myObj = (MyClass) perstObj.getContents();
//Make whatever changes you need to myObj
perstObj.setContents(myObj);
perstObj.commit();
```